# Can't resolve DNS for RDWeb externally

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, ip, fqdn, rdweb

I'm having trouble accessing RDWeb Access Server via internet browser using my FQDN (https://ifodgw.abacushub.io/rdweb) externally. I am able to access it externally using the elastic ip address 52.16.145.145, and internally using the FQDN. Pinging externally, from my local machine:

```
Pinging 52.16.145.145 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 52.16.145.145: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=113
...
>ping ifodgw.abacushub.io
Ping request could not find host idodgw.abacushub.io. Please check the name and try again.
```

My remote desktop services setup is on an AWS EC2 instance, using Windows Server 2012.

```
Instance ID:       i-1ce67396
Instance Type:     m3.large
Availability Zone: eu-west-1a
Instance state:    running
Status Checks:     2/2 checks passed
Alarm status:      None
Public DNS:        ec2-52-16-145-145.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Public IP:         52.16.145.145
```

I've created an A Name record with the FQDN and IP address on Linode's DNS Manager for the server in my domain zone. I also have a different A Name record hosted in the same domain zone for a similar setup on different AWS servers, in a different active directory with the same domain name, and this resolves correctly: https://gateway.abacushub.io/rdweb,

```
A/AAAA Records
Hostname    IP Address      TTL 
gateway     54.77.226.3     Default 
ifodgw      52.16.145.145   300 (5 minutes)
```

As a workaround, I'm able to add this line to my local hosts file:

> 52.16.145.145 ifodgw.abacushub.io

This isn't an ideal fix though, as I'd need to do this for every client machine.

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to expand on your problem and show what you've done. Suggest also including things like ping/curl to show connectivity. If you include the actual domain name and the elastic IP someone may be able to spot the actual problem - it's not like domain names or IP addresses are secret.

Answer (score 2):

According to the listed authoritative servers for `abacushub.io`, the specified subdomain does not actually exist:

```
% dig +norec @ns3.iwantmyname.net. ifodgw.abacushub.io

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> +norec @ns3.iwantmyname.net. ifodgw.abacushub.io
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 2191
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ifodgw.abacushub.io.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
abacushub.io.       3600    IN  SOA ns1.iwantmyname.net. info.12idn.com. 2015100904 86400 7200 3600000 3600

;; Query time: 30 msec
;; SERVER: 2a01:130:2000:118:89:146:248:96#53(2a01:130:2000:118:89:146:248:96)
;; WHEN: Fri Apr 15 10:46:40 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106
```

I note that the SOA record suggests that there's been no zone update since 2015-10-09.  You need to look into why the zone changes you've made in the control panel are not reaching those DNS servers.